# Vuestorefront is not working with "yarn start" + production, working in "yarn dev" developement mode

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, production, vue-storefront

I am using [vuestorefront](https://github.com/DivanteLtd/vue-storefront) and I have used [vuetique](https://github.com/AbsoluteWebServices/vuetique-theme) theme and customize it according to our needs.
This project is perfectly running on development mode and all sections are loading completely.
but when we run this vue project in production mode using `yarn start` the dynamic content and sections are not loading properly with data leaving error in the console like below.

```
TypeError: t.setAttribute is not a function at Object.setStyleScope
```

[image]

I have searched almost everything but not getting any clue where is the issue.
can anyone points out where the issue can be debugged?

Thanks